# redirect url codeigniter when product id changes in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I am having url like base_url/Category/productname-254

here 254 is Id for that product.

Also Category is coming by adding routing in route.php like
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1/$1';

if I change product Id from 254 to product Id 344 then it should redirect to 344 product page.

Like below URL:

http://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/cardiac-monitoring-advanced-technologies-and-global-market-55.html

if you change last number in above URL which is 55 to number 58 then it is redirecting to below URL
http://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/nanomaterials-58.html

**which is product page of product Id 58**.

Here is my function from where I am getting URL:

```
function get_report_url($reporttitle,$reportid){
        //$title1 = str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '',$reporttitle);
        $title1 = str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '',$reporttitle);
        $title1 = str_replace(array( ',','?' ), "-",$title1);
        $title1 = str_replace(array( "'", "&", "º","&deg;","ordm;" ), "",$title1);

        $title=explode(" ",$title1);
        //$title=explode(" ",$row['reportTitle']);
        $fintitle="";
        foreach($title as $words){
            $fintitle=$fintitle.$words.'-';
            }
        $fintitle=$fintitle.$reportid;  

        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT category FROM ur1 WHERE id=".$reportid);
        $cat = $query1->row();
        $url = base_url()."".$cat->category."/".$fintitle;
        //$url = base_url()."index/report/".$cat->category."/".$fintitle;
        return $url;
    }
```

Controller to go to above url:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function report($cat,$rep){
    $ttl = explode("-",$this->uri->segment(2));
    $reportid = end($ttl);
    //echo "reportid  ".$reportid;
    /*echo "category ".$cat;*/
    //exit;
    $this->load->model('show_model','',TRUE);
    $arr_result = $this->show_model->get_report_details($reportid);
    //echo "reportid  ".$reportid;
    /*print_r($arr_result);
    exit;*/
    $data['error'] = $arr_result[0];
    $data['result'] = $arr_result[1];
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/breadcrumbs');
    $this->load->view('pages/reportpage',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

}

route.php

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'index/report/$1/$1';
```

Any Help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Having some code would be helpful.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error it is just not redirecting.. staying on the same page

Comment: Without seeing view, controller, routes code it is hard to tell.

Comment: Edited question again... with controller and routes.

Comment: I can't see where `get_report_url($reporttitle, $reportid)` method is used in your code. First of, you [shouldn't name](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html) your controller as `Index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//go to application->config->routes.php  

$route['404_override'] = 'Category'; //override error page with category controller 
class Category extends MY_Controller {        
 function index($product_id=''){   
   //get product data using product id and load data on view   
  }  
 }
```